# Time complexity of removing duplicates in lists

Tags: time-complexity, arrays

### Question

I am wondering what is the minimum time complexity of get the unique value of a array in two conditions: keep the order or not.

For example, suppose we have a original array `[3,6,1,1,2]`. I want to get `[3,6,1,2]`, this result keeps the original order and drops duplicates. If there is no need to keep the original order, `[1,2,6,3]` or `[6,2,1,3]` works fine.

I think time complexity of not keeping the order is $O(n)$ using a hashtable.
Under keeping order condition, approch may have a time complexity of $O(n^2)$.

> So, Am I right? Can someone give a detailed prove the time complexity of the best in each condition?

### For more infomation:

I use Python, I find 2 python code for drop duplicates in a list.

1. [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)
2. [removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: You mix `list` and `array` without explanation. Please define `the unique value of [an] array`.

Comment: In general, a hash table will not guarantee constant time insertion in the worst case.

Comment: Establish a lower bound. Try and use "the *hashtable* idea" in a *constructive* proof. Think of a merge sort dropping duplicates.

Comment: @Juho In practice, you will be very hard pressed to find examples where hash tables take more than linear time. Especially for an array of integers,

Comment: I cant quite see how you would not keep the list order and how you would use n^2 operations when using a hash table to find the duplicates.

Comment: @gnasher729 Indeed, but clearly my comment was no objection to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The running time is expected $O(n)$ for both problems.  Simply scan over the input list, and as you examine each item, add it to the hashtable; if it wasn't already present, output it.  The running time is $(n)$ because, with a suitable hash function, the expected time it takes to insert or look up an item in a hash table is $O(1)$.

The worst-case running time with this approach is $O(n^2)$, but you can make the probability of this happening exponentially small with a suitably chosen hash function.

Alternatively, if you care a lot about worst-case running time, you can replace the hashtable with a self-balancing binary tree and achieve $O(n \log n)$ worst-case running time for both problems.

Comment: If you care about performance and worry about worst-case running time, you could start with a hash table, count the operations, and switch to a suitable binary tree if your hash table has used more than n log n operations - which will likely never happen. So you have expected time O(n) and worst case O (n log n). Make sure the binary tree code is well tested (because it will almost never run, so bugs might hide).